# Toggle Classes with query based upon ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax call to my functions.php file in order to query a DB and find out if the field "is_recurring" is 1 or 0.  The 1 or 0 comes from a dropdown selection.  Based upon what's returned from the php function, I'm trying to add and remove the "hide" class from my div where some text is displayed.

Is there a better way to write this code?  Also, if I select the dropdown menu back and forth a few times, it seems to get confused and doesn't add/remove the class correctly.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    data: {action: "toggle", category:category}
}); 
request.done(function(response){
    if(response == 1) {
        if($('#toggle').hasClass("hide")) {
            $('#toggle').hide().removeClass("hide").fadeIn(900);      
        } else { 
            $('#toggle').fadeOut(900).addClass("hide");
        };
    } else if(response != 1) {
        if($('#toggle').hasClass("hide")) {
            exit;           
        } else {
            $('#toggle').fadeOut(900).removeClass("hide"); 
        };
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you want to show toggle div on response ? like if 1 than hide while on 0 show right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to don't traverse the DOM many times :

```
request.done(function(response){
    var ele = $('#toggle');
    if(response == 1) {
        if(ele.hasClass("hide")) {
            ele.hide().removeClass("hide").fadeIn(900);      
        } else { 
            ele.fadeOut(900).addClass("hide");
        };
    } else if(response != 1) {
        if(ele.hasClass("hide")) {
            exit;           
        } else {
           ele.fadeOut(900).removeClass("hide"); 
        };
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(response == 1) {
    $('#toggle').removeClass('.hide').fadeIn();
}
else{
    $('#toggle').addClass('.hide').fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using based on @Tyagi's suggestion, with a couple modifications.

```
request.done(function(response){
    var ele = $('#toggle');
    if(response == 1) {
        if(ele.hasClass("hide")) {
            ele.hide().removeClass("hide").fadeIn(900);      
        } else { 
            exit;
        };
    } else if(response != 1) {
        if(ele.hasClass("hide")) {
            exit;           
        } else {
           ele.fadeOut(900).addClass("hide"); 
        };
    };
});
```